# How to index a nested cell array using a vector of indices

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, nested

I want to build a tree in matlab as a nested cell array.
Thus I have a data structure like.

```
T={ { [1;1] {[1;2;1] [1;2;2]}} 2}.
```

The depth of the tree is not fixed.
How can I index the entries of T in a way like

```
T(i)
```

Respectively, is there another easy way to implement a tree in matlab?

---

Edit: I am not interested in an indexing like T{1}{2}{1}, since this type of indexing is not suitable for nested cell arrays with variable depth.
I want something like

```
i=[1 2 1];  
T(i)=3;
```

Thus, afterwards T is

```
{ { [1;1] {3 [1;2;2]}} 2}.
```

Comment: Matlab Central has an implementation of a tree data structure. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35623-tree-data-structure-as-a-matlab-class).

Answer (score 0):

```
T={ { [1;1] {[1;2;1] [1;2;2]}} 2} ;
```

You should know about cell indexing...we call matrix indexing using (), where as a cell indexing using {}. You can access your T data like below:

```
T{1}
T{1}{1}
T{1}{2}{1} etc...
```